# Stack v-cards within n columns

Tags: vue.js

I have `items: Item[]`, from which I build a list of `v-card`. I need them to be built this way:
[image: Imgur].

**Specs**:

- Every card has the same width, but a random height
- The next card to be stacked must be in the least filled column (left priority)
- The columns number can change with the screen width
- `items` can change, so the columns have to dynamically change

I've found a solution with pure JS, where I build the cards in a hidden div, I create n divs in which I clear and clone manually the cards in the right column. But I think it's a dirty way to do that, and the dynamic change fails.

Comment: Do a search for "css masonry layout"

Comment: Thanks, I never heard about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've found the solution, thanks to David Weldon, with **css masonry layout**.

I've my items  as data.

```js
data: function() {
    return {
        items: [
            { id: 1, text: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'},
            { id: 2, text: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'},
            { id: 3, text: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'},
            { id: 4, text: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'},
            { id: 5, text: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'}
        ],
    }
}
```

I build the cards in a simple div.

```html
<div class="items">
    <v-card class="item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.text }}
    </v-card>
</div>
```

Then make the css.

```css
.items {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Make it responsive */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .items {
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-water-b9rk4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the sandbox.

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since `vuetify`s grid system doesn't allow this kind of wrapping. You can use css flex-box to achieve this kind of layout.

> Define a container column layout with wrap option :

```
#flex-container {
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
```

> Set your items flex and height styles in the v-for loop :

```
 <div id="flex-container">
    <template v-for="(item,i) in items">
      <div
        class="item"
        :key="i"
        :style="getStyle(item.height)"
      >{{item.height}}%</div>
    </template>
  </div>
```

> getStyle method

```
getStyle(height) {
      return {flex: `1 1 ${height}%`, 'max-height': `${height}%` }
    }
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-hdrgp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the sandbox.

Comment: Mmm I'm not good enough with flex css to really understand what happens, and I've  done some research with **css masonry layout** as said @DavidWeldon, and I think this is my prefered solution.